# Share one interface instance on whole application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I'm creating an application based on Hazelcast and spring-boot-starter-web. The application structure is:
Book controller-> BookService interface-> BookServiceImplementation-> put into hazelcast queue

Author controller-> AuthorService interface-> AuthorServiceImplementation-> put into hazelcast queue.

For that purpose i need one class that contains hazelcastInstance to share it in all services so i created blackboard interface but because i use `@Autowired` it is creating new instance for every service and i need to set hazelcast instance again.
My code so far:

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("book")
public ResponseEntity<Void> getBookDetails(
        @RequestParam(value = "bookId", required = false) Long bookId) {
    bookService.add(bookId);
return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Service impl:**

```
@Service("bookService")
public class BookServiceImpl extends BaseService implements BookService {
@Override
    public void add(Long bookId) {
                    blackboard.add(bookId, Listeners.BOOK_QUEUE_NAME);
            
    }
```

**BaseService:**

```
public class BaseService {
@Autowired
    protected Blackboard blackboard;
    public void loadInstance(ClientConfig clientConfig) {
        HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstanceClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        blackboard.setHazelcastInstance(hazelcastInstanceClient);
    }
}
```

**Blackboard interface impl:**

```
@Component("blackboard")
public class BlackboardImpl implements Blackboard {

    private HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

    @Override
    public HazelcastInstance getHazelcastInstance() {

        return hazelcastInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        this.hazelcastInstance = hazelcastInstance;
    }

    
    @Override
    public boolean add(Object obj, String collectionId) {

        IQueue<Object> queue = hazelcastInstance.getQueue(collectionId);
        return queue.add(obj);
    }
    }
```

Comment: "because i use @Autowired it is creating new instance for every service" - um, no? Where is it created? If it comes from spring auto config, there will be the single instance shared across all services.

Comment: On my main class i`m using 
```AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
    HazelcastClientApplication.class);
  context.getBean(BaseService.class).loadInstance(clientConfig);``` to initialize the hazelcast Instance at the start and it is working. When i system.out.println it it is ok but then on service is again null. Can you explain me why?

Comment: @ВладимирГичев How much do you know about Spring and Spring Boot? Do you how about scopes, e.g., Singleton? Do you how that Spring Boot will create a HazelcastInstance for you if you provide a hazelcast.xml or a Config bean?

Comment: @Nicolas
How much do you know about Spring and Spring Boot - mid level
Do you how about scopes, e.g., Singleton - yes
Do you how that Spring Boot will create a HazelcastInstance for you if you provide a hazelcast.xml or a Config bean? - No, until now i used very old hazelcast and now i'm trying to migrate to 3.9.3

Comment: First, migrate to at least Hazelcast 4. Then, remove the Blackboard component. Finally, add a hazelcast.xml to trigger Spring Boot to create a Singleton-scoped Hazelcast bean. Inject it wherever you need (please use construction injection)

Comment: @Nicolas I migrated to hazelcast 4.2.4 but I don't want to use any xml/yaml files in my application. Is there any other way to create this Hazelcast bean?